# JavaScript connection not starting and function not executing on a JQuery and SignalR web form application

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net, signalr

I have a ASP.NET chat application. Using JavaScript, Jquery and Signalr. However my connection does not start to post the message. The browser does prompt me to enter my alias however when l write my message. It does not post it. [This is a snippet of the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Loqtl.png)

C# class :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR;
using Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Hubs;

namespace Synergince
{
   [HubName("chatHub")]
public class ChatHub : Hub
{

    public void Send(string name, string message)
    {

        Clients.All.broadcastMessage(name, message);
    }

}
}
```

JavaScript code :

```
<div class="container">
<input type="text" id="message" />
<input type="button" id="sendmessage" value="Send" />
<input type="hidden"id="displayname" />
<ul id="discussion">
</ul>
</div>

    //Script references
<script type="text/javascript" src="Scripts/jquery-1.4.1.min.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="Scripts/jquery.signalR-1.2.1.js">
</script>
<script src='<%: ResolveClientUrl("~/signalr/hubs") %>'></script>


<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
            //declare a proxy to reference the hub
            var chat = $.connection.chatHub;

            //function for the hub to call to broadcast messages
            chat.client.broadcastMessage = function (name, message) {
                $('#discussion').append('<li><strong>' + name + '</strong>:&nbsp;&nbsp;' + message + '</li>');
            };

            //Get the user name and store it to prepend to messages
            $('#displayname').val(prompt('Enter preferred alias:', ''));

            //initial focus on textbox
            $('#message').focus();

            //connection start
            $.connection.hub.start().done(function () {
                $('#sendmessage').click(function () {
                    var Name = $('<div />').text($('#displayname').val()).html();
                    var Msg = $('<div />').text($('#message').val()).html();

                    //call send method to hub
                    chat.server.send(Name, Msg);

                    //clear textbox and set for next input
                    $('#message').val('').focus();

                });

            });

        });
   </script>
</form>
```

Browser debugger error is:

> Uncaught TypeError: $.Deferred is not a function

To this line :

```
 $.connection.hub.start().done(function () {
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you are trying to achieve with the two VARs below.

```
        $.connection.hub.start().done(function () {
            $('#sendmessage').click(function () {
                var Name = $('<div />').text($('#displayname').val()).html();
                var Msg = $('<div />').text($('#message').val()).html();

                //call send method to hub
                chat.server.send(Name, Msg);

                //clear textbox and set for next input
                $('#message').val('').focus();

            });
```

I can only assume you want to send the value of the input boxes. Essentially the same as the sample Chat on the [SignalR site](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/signalr/overview/getting-started/tutorial-getting-started-with-signalr).

Change your function to get the "val" of the input:

```
        $.connection.hub.start().done(function () {
            $('#sendmessage').click(function () {
                // Call the Send method on the hub.
                chat.server.send($('#displayname').val(), $('#message').val());
                // Clear text box and reset focus for next comment.
                $('#message').val('').focus();
            });
        });
```

Comment: The browser still shows a Uncaught TypeError: $.Deferred is not a function error

Comment: Try updating your hub reference as shown below, I can't tell if you are actually resolving and connecting. You could also try updating to 2.x of SignalR and walking through the tutorial again.

<!--Reference the autogenerated SignalR hub script. -->
<script src="signalr/hubs"></script>

Comment: my hub script is fine. When the browser runs it passes information through it. Its not the hub